# jQueryUI Resizable doesn't respond on option change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I use jQuery UI Resizable module and looks like it doesn't react when I try to pass an option after it was initialised.

So if I initialize element:

```
$('.blabla').resizable();
```

And then try to add option:

```
$('.blabla').resizable("option","aspectRatio",true);
```

Nothing happens. By checking option-by-option I figured out that some of them work and some doesn't... What's the issue? For sure, 'aspectRatio' doesn't work and 'ghost' works.

Here is simple jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/k8gY8/1/

Comment: Seems like [a bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4186)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in Jquery UI. Especially, that one is almost 5(five!!!) years old and was reported many times on jquery ui forums.
Here is the ticket:
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4186

Current workaround is like that:

```
(function() {
    var oldSetOption = $.ui.resizable.prototype._setOption;
    $.ui.resizable.prototype._setOption = function(key, value) {
        oldSetOption.apply(this, arguments);
        if (key === "aspectRatio") {
            this._aspectRatio = !!value;
        }
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a known issue: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4186

So, as suggested, you can override the prototype `mouseStart` event:

```
$(function () {
    $.extend($.ui.resizable.prototype, (function (orig) {
        return {
            _mouseStart: function (event) {
                this._aspectRatio = !! (this.options.aspectRatio);
                return (orig.call(this, event));
            }
        };
    })($.ui.resizable.prototype["_mouseStart"]));
});
```

at the top of your code and il will work.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ajYgM/

Comment: Ha-ha, I found the same ticket 2 minutes ago :) But anyway, thanks!

Comment: Nice, it's a bit old, it not seems to be the faster patched issue ever :-)